# Adding Items to a DataGrid (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

### Goal

To add a list of a custom class object (DamagedItems) to a DataGrid using the Model, View, ViewModel (MVVM) way of doing things.

I want the user to be able to create entries of damaged parts (deemed improper during inspection of a machine).

### What I have done

I have created:

- A window: **wDamagedItems.xaml** in which it's `DataContext` is set to `DamagedItemViewModel`
- A Model: **DamagedItemModel.vb** which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`
- A ViewModel: **DamagedItemViewModel.vb** where I set properties of classes such as my `DamagedItemModel`
- An ObservableCollection: **DamagedItemList.vb** which inherits an `ObservableCollection(Of DamagedItemModel)`

Since my DataContext is set to the **DamagedItemViewModel**, here is how I setup the properties:

```
Public Class DamagedItemViewModel
    Private _DamagedItem As DamagedItemModel
    Private _Add As ICommand
    Private _DamagedItems As DamagedItemList

    Public Property DamagedItem As DamagedItemModel
        Get
            Return _DamagedItem
        End Get
        Set(value As DamagedItemModel)
            _DamagedItem = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property DamagedItems As DamagedItemList
        Get
            Return _DamagedItems
        End Get
        Set(value As DamagedItemList)
            _DamagedItems = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Add As ICommand
        Get
            Return _Add
        End Get
        Set(value As ICommand)
            _Add = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Sub New()
        DamagedItem = New DamagedItemModel("", "", "")
        DamagedItems = New DamagedItemList
        Add = New DamagedItemAddEntryCommand(Me)
    End Sub

    Public Function CanUpdate() As Boolean
        If DamagedItem.Description = "" Then Return False
        If DamagedItem.Initiales = "" Then Return False
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Sub AddEntry()
        DamagedItems.Add(DamagedItem) 'Items get added to the datagrid
        DamagedItem = New DamagedItemModel 'Does not seem to clear textboxes
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

Here is how my XAML is set up:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DamagedItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,90,12,0" Name="DataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="229" / >

<TextBox Text="{Binding DamagedItem.Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="249" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding DamagedItem.Initiales, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="249" />
```

As you can see, my textboxes are bound to my Model (which is contained in my ViewModel, which is bound to that Window's DataContext). Whenever I click on my "Add" button, whatever is in the textbox gets added to the DataGrid, but the content in the text boxes stay there.

---

This step is fine, I write in what I want to add and click on "Add"

[image: Damaged item about to be added]

After clicking on "Add" i get the following results in the DataGrid, which is fine. The issue is my text boxes are still filled with data yet the Model was cleared (see code after **DamagedItemViewModel** `AddEntry` method).

[image: Damaged item added, but still displaying]

Now when I try to add the following text:

- Description: "*Part is bent*"
- Initiales: "*A.C*"

I get the following result:

The first letter typed in the description gets inputted in the first entry of the DataGrid, then it erases the text in the description textbox. Only then can I keep typing what I want. The same thing occurs for the initiales text box.

[image: First letter being added in old class]

Any ideas? If you wish to see more of my code, suggest which portion I should add.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Instead of creating the damagedItem right away, wait until you click add to construct it. Change your textboxes to be bound to string properties `Description` and `Initiales`

Comment: @Shoe Umm ... Not sure I follow here. My properties `Description` and `Initiales` are bound to string properties already in the DamagedItemModel.vb class. I just use a property in my ViewModel to refer to that class

Comment: What I mean is that you should set up ViewModel properties `Description` and `Initiales` and use those properties to fill your model. Directly binding to your model is missing the point of MVVM

Comment: @Shoe If I understand correctly, my Model which contains Description And Initiales should not be refered to by my ViewModel? Instead, I should have the properties `Description` and `Initiales` directly in my viewModel? What's the point of having a Model then?

Comment: Your viewmodel should be interacting with your model, not your view with your model. You could have your viewmodel properties returning your model properties, or you could have viewmodel properties that fill your model when some action takes place. The point of the model is data access. You save your actual data to databases, not extra junk like public events, commands, and temporary view state variables which reside in the viewmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, I remember running into this one.  You have to implement iNotifyPropertyCHnaged.  This is how the viewmodel class "notifies" the user interface that there has been a change to the underlying property of a binding:

look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

You will have to implement this for every property you want reflected back to the view.  SO what I do is have a base viewmodel class (ViewModelBase which exposes method RasiePropertyChanged) which implements iNotifyPropertyChanged and then my viewmodles inherit from it.  Then I notify the property changed in the property set of the property:

ie:

```
    Public Property Selection As job
        Get
            Return Me._Selection
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As job)
            If _Selection Is value Then
                Return
            End If
            _PreviousJob = _Selection
            _Selection = value
            RaisePropertyChanged(SelectionPropertyName)
        End Set
    End Property
```

This seems frustrating at first but is needed to keep the decoupling that MVVM supports.  Its easy to implement.

Comment: Yep I have my `INotifyPropertyChanged`setup on each property in my DamagedItemModel.vb. That's what I don't understand ... I didn't put any `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my DamagedItemViewModel ... Does that make a difference?

Comment: Nvm, you were right. I setup `INotifyPropertyChanged` on my ViewModel as well and now it works perfect. Thank you

Comment: glad to help,  the NotifyProperty changed works from the model if you bind to an object from that model, but in this case the property is from the viewmodel.  It happens to me all the time.